# how to transfer port in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding

I am running a Debian guest VM on Oracle VirtualBox on my Windows machine. I have a DNS server (bind) on the guest that I'd like to see externally from outside the guest OS. How do I give this access to port 53?

```
My public ip = e.e.e.e
My private ip = i.i.i.i
Virtual box ip = v.v.v.v
```

There is no bind/dns running on host.

Comment: What do you mean by transfer? Do you mean have a specific port visible externally?

Comment: **YES**, I'm running debian in virtual box with bind and apache. now i want to answers to dns queries coming to my machine (host os) through my virtual box debian (guest os).

Comment: thank you @DravSloan, for putting nice stuff in the question in order to make it more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

By default Oracle's Virtualbox sets its networking to a NAT mode. In this senario you will have to set it to bridging. Go to the VM in question (in VirtualBox) and edit its settings and set the network mode from NAT to bridging. Note that DHCP will no longer be provided by Virtual Box, but by your standard network DHCP provider if you have one. (If your windows box is set to obtain an IP address automatically then you already have a local DHCP server).

To pick up the new dhcp server's provided address run `ps auxwww` and look for a process called `dhclient`. Kill this process and then re-run it with the same command arguments. You should then have a new IP address. Restart your name server `/etc/init.d/bind9 restart`, and then you should be able to use the DNS server from the IP address provided by `ifconfig`. (So long as a firewall is not blocking it).

If your Debian guest has no DNS already, then you will have to install it with `apt-get install bind9` (ran as root).

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote `There is no bind/dns running on guest.` but in fact `**There is no bind/dns running on host.**`. the guest has bind 9. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and correct that :)

Comment: I did same. **BUT NO RESULTS**  [http://www.intodns.com/taxdelhi.com](http://www.intodns.com/taxdelhi.com) says nameserver not responding. However it works if i do it on real physical machine with debian.

Comment: You will need to port NAT from your External IP (I assume on either firewall host or Router), to the VM's IP address and DNS port.

Comment: i did so, but no results.